# How does the laplacian act on a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How does the laplacian act on a vector?

I mean

Let

$$
A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)
$$

which is right

$$
\nabla^{2}A=(\nabla^{2}A_x,\nabla^{2}A_y,\nabla^{2}A_z)
$$
Or
$$
\nabla^{2}A=(\nabla^{2}_x A_x,\nabla^{2}_y A_y,\nabla^{2}_z A_z)
$$

Also, if $\phi$ is a scalar then is $\nabla^{2}\phi$ a vector or a scalar.
Thanks

Comment: (1) The first one is right. (2) It's a scalar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del

Comment: @Mathaholic: Indeed, the first one is the correct one, but who exactly do you say is a scalar? From my knowledge, nobody is. Maybe you were thinking of something else?

Comment: @Mathaholic, But from the definition of the laplacian $\nabla^{2}\phi=\nabla(\nabla.\phi)-\nabla\times(\nabla\times\phi)$ So how could the left side be a scalar and right side be a vector?

Comment: I think from definition $\nabla^2 \phi = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \phi)$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta u = \mathrm{div} \cdot \nabla u $

where

$\displaystyle \Delta := \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^{2}_i}$

$\displaystyle \mathrm{div} = \nabla:= \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} , \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} , \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} \right )$

$\cdot$ is scalar product.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian preserves "tensor order", eg, the Laplacian of an $n$th order tensor field is an $n$th order tensor field. Therefore the Laplacian of a scalar field is a scalar field.

For vector fields, in a *linear* coordinate system, the vector Laplacian $\nabla^2\mathbf{A}$ can be calculated by calculating the scalar Laplacian of each component separately, eg. if $\mathbf{A}=A_1\mathbf{e}_1+A_2\mathbf{e}_2+A_3\mathbf{e}_3$, then $\nabla^2\mathbf{A}=(\nabla^2A_1)\mathbf{e}_1+(\nabla^2A_2)\mathbf{e}_2+(\nabla^2A_3)\mathbf{e}_3$.

For curved coordinate systems, this formula does not hold, because the variations of the basis vectors also need to be taken into account.